# Amazon RDS or S3 Bucket to store game scores?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am building a game using Unity and I want to track how well an individual does over a period of time. So I want to save their time, level, high score, etc. I am writing the scores to either a .txt file or .json file at the end of the game. The game will be deployed to Android OS (maybe IOs). I want the file to be sent off before the game returns to the home menu.

I wanted to know what is the better option for collecting the game data. Amazon RDS or S3 Bucket?

Comment: without knowing schema, access patterns and load, its tough to say.. but DynamoDb should solve several such use cases with ease, if we can store json that is not super huge.

Comment: Generally, you want a database of some version, since even something as simple as a high-score table would be trivial in most databases, but require a lot of work to get out of S3.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala is there a big difference between DynamoDb and Amazon RDS MariaDB?

Comment: MariaDB is also a relational database like MySql where as DynamoDb is NoSql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Text File use S3, it is great.
If you have JSON values, Use DynamoDb.
[AWS Dynamodb](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/)

If your JSON object is less than 4KB, DynamoDB is significantly faster than S3 for individual operations.Refer to this [Link](https://serverless.pub/s3-or-dynamodb/).

But yes, No RDS if you have only JSON. NoSQL is great. [Dynamodb]